# How do (co)limits in posets of subobjects relate to (co)limits in ambient category?

Tags: ct.category-theory, linear-algebra, topos-theory

Sorry if this is elementary.

Let $C$ be a category, $X$ an object in $C$ and let $S(X)$ denote the poset of subobjects of $X$.

According to the [nlab entry](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/subobject#the_poset_of_subobjects), if $C$ has all limits and co-limits, so does $S(X)$. It's a little unclear to me why this is true, and in particular how to construct a limit in $S(X)$ using limits in $C$.

For example, in the category $Mod_R$ of modules over a ring $R$, $S(X)$ is the poset of submodules of $X$, and the limit and colimit are respectively the intersection and "sum" of submodules. It's not clear to me immediately how these relate to limits and colimits in $Mod_R$.

Hence the title of the question:

How do (co)limits in poset of subobjects relate to (co)limits in ambient category?

Comment: Brief response on limits since I don't have time to write a full answer: $S(X)$ is equivalent to a sucategory of $C/X$ and the forgetful functor preserves [connected limits](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/connected+limit). Any limit in $S(X)$ can be made into a connected limit by adding the terminal object into the diagram.

Comment: Is it really claimed there what you say is? In fact I am in doubt about colimits. A candidate for the coproduct $A_1\lor A_2$ of subobjects of $A$ is the image of the morphism $A_1\sqcup A_2\to A$ from their coproduct to $A$, but there might be categories with all limits and colimits but without decent image factorizations. Even the image of the morphism from the initial object to $A$ is not clear to me. Also, I am not sure infinite meets of subobjects do exist.

Comment: If $S(X)$ is small, then the inclusion $S(X)\subset C/X$ has a left adjoint (given by the obvious limit), so $S(X)$ has colimits as well, but they need not be the same as in $C$.

Comment: @MarcHoyois You are right. Still, $S(X)$ might fail to be small. I think.

Comment: I don't see it claimed on the nLab page that if $C$ has all limits and colimits then so does $S(X)$.  It defines notation for meets and joins, and then shows how to construct them in terms of limits and colimits *if* $C$ is a (pre)topos.

Comment: The answers are basically all here in the comments, but maybe someone should summarize them as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To summarize what's been said in comments:

- If $C$ has small limits, then so does $S(X)$: they are inherited from $C/X$, which inherits them from $C$ by adding $X$ as a terminal object in the diagram being taken a limit of.
- In particular, therefore, if $C$ is well-powered, so that $S(X)$ is small, then it is a small complete lattice and hence also has all colimits, constructed by the adjoint functor theorem.  However, they are not *a priori* related to colimits in $C$, and not well-behaved (e.g. not stable under pullback).
- If $C$ has a factorization system where the right class is the subobject inclusions, then joins in $S(X)$ can be constructed as the images of coproducts in $C$.
- If $C$ is a pretopos, then finite joins in $S(X)$ can be constructed as pushouts under intersections, as described at the nLab page.